# How to auto fill foreign key id in many-to-one relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, one-to-many, laravel-5.7

I have two models called `Question` and `Factor`. One `Factor` belongs to many `Question` and Every `Question` has one `Factor`. I define this many-to-one relationship in my models.I want to store a factor in `QuestionController`.I find the question object and create a factor through that question.When I test this function in `Postman`,the factor successfully stored but `factor_id` don't insert automaticly to question table.I don't want create the question object through a factor (revers of this manner). Because the factor object is created when the payment is done and before question object was created.How to do it?
this is question table:

```
 Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('factor_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('factor_id')->references('factors')->on('id')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

This is factor table:

```
 Schema::create('factors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('number_factor')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('total_price',15,2)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is question model:

```
  class Question extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];
    public function factors()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Factor::class,'factor_id');
    }
}
```

This is factor model:

```
 class Factor extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class,'factor_id');
    }
}
```

This is `QuestionController`:

```
 public function storeFactor(Request $request,$questionId)
{
    $question=Question::find($questionId);
    if(is_null($question)){
        return response()->json([
            'success'=>false,
            'message'=>'This question is not exist!'
        ],404);
    }
    $question->factors()->create($request->all());
    $question->save();
    return response()->json([
        'success'=>true,
        'message'=>'Factor successfully Stored.'
    ],200);
}
```

And this is my route:

```
Route::post('question/storeFactor/{id}','API\QuestionController@storeFactor');
```

Comment: You could just create the factor separately, retaining this in a `$variable`. Then update the `$question` with the `$factor->id`. Or are you trying to find a way to do this using eloquent?

Comment: @thisiskelvin. I prefer to find a way to do this using eloquent but also your solution is good.

Comment: Ok then. You are able to use the `save()` relation method on an already created model instance. Create the factor first, then save the question again. e.g. `$factor->questions()->save($question);`

Comment: Or I think you can use the `associate()` method.

Comment: @thisiskelvin: It solved.If you like, post your answer to select as best answer.I use of  `$factor->questions()->save($question);`.

Comment: Ok then I've added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to use the `save()` relation method on an already created model instance.

Create the factor first, then save the question again. e.g. `$factor->questions()->save($question);`